# How to store and re-use local storage data using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to using local storage. Can anyone teach me how I can get the value I've placed in the textarea, and once I click the done button it will store in the `.result` class. Also once I've input again there's another it will store again in the `.result` class? Please anyone can help me with this?

```js
$(".Done").on("click", function() {
  var test = $(".title").val();
  localStorage.setItem("title", test);
});
```

```css
.result {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="title"></textarea>
<div class="Done">Done</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot directly access the value of the textbox by selecting it's class as it will give you an array of elements. Select the first element (which is probably the textbox) then get the value. The `localStorage.setItem()` is the correct syntax

Comment: @RifatBinReza `You cannot directly access the value of the textbox by selecting it's class as it will give you an array of elements` . No, it won't . He has only one textarea element with class ' title'. It's jquery, not plain javascript where you have `getElementsByClassName` -> i guess that's what you were thinking about

Comment: @MihaiT You're right, I wasn't thinking about that

Answer (score 2):

To achieve your goal you need to do two things. Firstly set the `text()` of `.result` based on the value in the `textarea` when the button is clicked.

Secondly you need to check if the `title` is set in local storage when the page loads, and if it is, then set the value of `.result` with that content.

The logic would look like this:

```js
let setResult = title => $('.result').text(title || '');

jQuery($ => {
  setResult(localStorage.getItem('title')); // set on load    

  $(".Done").on("click", function() {
    let title = $(".title").val();
    setResult(title); // set on click
    localStorage.setItem("title", title);
  });
});
```

Here's a [working example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/68bynv3m/) as the SO snippet editor is sandboxed and doesn't allow access to local storage.

Comment: Thanks, @Rory McCrossan for this Idea.